# Executing Oracle SQL Query with multiple bind variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I have scenario where my SQL query with multiple bind variables (1 repeats multiple times in the same query) needs to be executed with python cx_Oracle db connection.

the query somewhat looks like below:

```
select * from tablea where colA=:cola and colB=:colb and colc=:cola and and cold=:cola
```

when I execute in the connection query cx_Oracle cursor in python, I am not getting expected results and suspect that variable binding is not happening properly.

Below is the python code:

```
data=cur.execute(qryStr,dict(colb='value1',cola= 'value2')).fetchall()
```

is this fine?

Would this be treated as follows:

```
select * from tablea where colA='value2' and colB='value1' and colc='value2' and and cold='value2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

With this schema:

```
drop table mytable;
create table mytable (cola varchar2(20), colb varchar2(20), colc varchar2(20), cold varchar2(20));
insert into mytable values ('value2', 'value1', 'value2', 'value2');
commit;
```

This code:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    qryStr = """select * from mytable where colA=:cola and colB=:colb and colc=:cola and cold=:cola"""
    data=cursor.execute(qryStr,dict(colb='value1',cola= 'value2')).fetchall()
    print(data)
```

gives:

```
[('value2', 'value1', 'value2', 'value2')]
```